# Pandoc ignoring html tags when converting from Markdown to Asciidoc

Tags: html, markdown, converters, pandoc, asciidoc

I'm trying to convert a document from Markdown to Asciidoc using Pandoc converter.
In my md documents there are some html pieces. After converting all the html tags (for example `<a>...</a>`) just disappear but I need them to be converted (e.g. to adoc links) or at least to be saved as they are.

Command that I'm running:

```
pandoc -f markdown-smart -s -o output.adoc -t asciidoc input.md
```

Input document in .md:

```
# Collections and Data Structures

Document text.

<a target='_blank' href='https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/17cfb8e65ead377bf1b4598d8a9869144142c84e/base/essentials.jl#L897-L903' class='documenter-source'>source</a><br>

Document text.
```

Current output in .adoc:

```
== Collections and Data Structures

Document text.

source

Document text.
```

How to make Pandoc save all the html tags and convert them (in perfect scenario)? I tried all the relevant settings and couldn't find the solution.

Desired output in .adoc:

```
== Collections and Data Structures

Document text.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/17cfb8e65ead377bf1b4598d8a9869144142c84e/base/essentials.jl#L897-L903[source]

Document text.
```

Answer (score 0):

A viable yet somewhat hacky method is to let pandoc convert to HTML first. E.g.:

```
pandoc -t html input.md | pandoc -f html o out.adoc
```

The tags will be included in HTML, so the second invocation of pandoc gets a document in a single format (HTML) instead of one in a mixed format.